# Snowpipe: Load base64 encoded JSON to table

Tags: json, base64, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a JSON file in s3, with base64 encoded JSON events. The decoded events will be of format

```
 {
    "payload": <bytes>,
    "context": {
        "metadata1": "metadata1_val",
        "metadata2": "metadata2_val"
     }
 }
```

where payload is base64 encoded JSON as well. Decoded payload will be of format

```
{
    "event_key1": "event_val1",
    "event_key2": "event_val2",
    "event_key3": "event_val3",
 }
```

Since Snowflake [stage file formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions) are restricted to CSV, JSON, AVRO, ORC, PARQUET, XML, without any direct support for binary format, we created a custom JSON file format as follows

```
create or replace file format BINARY_JSON_FORMAT
  type = 'JSON'
  BINARY_FORMAT = 'BASE64'
  strip_outer_array = true;
```

Couldn't get this to load binary data into a single column to be decoded accordingly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE TEST_STAGE
 storage_integration = <storage_integration>
 url='s3://bukit/test/'
 file_format = BINARY_JSON_FORMAT;

// The following could not parse the file
select parse_json(base64_decode_string($1)):payload as payload from @TEST_STAGE/test-file;
```

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved? We want to wrap this `select` in a `copy into` statement to create a snowpipe to ingest data from s3.

```
COPY INTO TEST_TABLE (
  event_key1,
  event_key2,
  event_key3
) from (
  select 
    parse_json(base64_decode_string($1)):payload.event_key1 event_key1,
    parse_json(base64_decode_string($1)):payload.event_key2 event_key2,
    parse_json(base64_decode_string($1)):payload.event_key3 event_key3,
  from @TEST_STAGE
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well years ago I did the following

```
-- SETUP
CREATE TABLE history_diags(
unit_id NUMBER,
time TIMESTAMP_NTZ,
data VARIANT);

CREATE TABLE raw_history_diags(
unit_id NUMBER,
time TIMESTAMP_NTZ,
data STRING);

CREATE STAGE point_history 
URL = 's3://bucket_name/' 
CREDENTIALS = ( creds stuff ) 
  COMMENT = 'S3 bucket for history data';


-- PROCESSING  
COPY INTO raw_history_diags
FROM '@point_history/' 
    pattern='.*diag_history_.*'
    file_format = 'POINT_RAW';


INSERT INTO HISTORY_DIAGS(unit_id, time, data)
  SELECT 
      unit_id,
      time, 
      iff(data is not null,unpack_base64_tids(data),'{}'::variant)
  FROM RAW_HISTORY_DIAGS;

DELETE FROM RAW_HISTORY_DIAGS;
```

where `unpack_base64_tids` was fundamentally `base64_decode_string`
and thus you should be able to combine those via something like..

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (event_key1, event_key2, event_key3)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        json.payload.event_keys1 AS event_key1
        json.payload.event_keys2 AS event_key2
        json.payload.event_keys3 AS event_key3
    FROM (
        SELECT parse_json(base64_decode_string($1)) AS json
        FROM @TEST_STAGE/test-file
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works great for inserts, but when I wrap the nested select in a `COPY INTO` I get `SQL compilation error: COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import.` Since Snowpipe is a wrapper on top of `COPY INTO`, I couldn't get it to auto ingest file with binary format, if underlying `COPY INTO` doesn't have support for nested selects.

Comment: Snowpipe, that is the forcing element. To be honest, we never used snowpipe because it didn't exist, so we rolled our own framework, and it's consternates never offered a "step up" to offset the loss of behavior, when it was rolled out. We would load the raw data from S3 into a table, and then transform that into our destination tables via a select or stream, and thus had, the raw json data, and the way to used it, always accessible (thus ELT). I think I have heard of people using stored procedures from snowpipe, so you could perhaps ingest into a temp table, and transform it out via the proc.

Comment: Agreed, the recommendation from Snowflake was comparable 1. Data is loaded into a staging table from Snowpipe.
2. Have a stream on the staging table
3. Have a task based on the Stream has data (the task can call a procedure which can transform/decode your data, by reading from the stream and insert into your target table). Given the scope of the project, and our timeline, we deployed a lambda upstream to decode data landing in s3 which seems like an easier route than having to maintain another ETL pipeline

Comment: ah, I am deeply of the opinion all processing should happen in SQL, and it is pure functional with no scale required, aka SQL is X in aws Lambda are equal. The glory of doing the transform in snowflake is when you discover the breaking change you have all the raw data there already. It's rather easy to reprocess and replace tables/views.

Comment: I totally agree with the sentiment here to decode everything in SQL, the Lambda in question deserializes everything as JSON so unless the underlying data is malformed, shouldn't result in any decoding errors and we also persist the raw data in s3 so as to not lose any events.